# Failed to fetch from git@github.com

Tags: git, jenkins

Okay, I am a newbie to Jenkins.

I'm reading [Jenkins: The Definitive Guide](http://isbn.directory/book/978-1-4493-0535-2) and am attempting to set up the first example.

I'm having issues and I've searched and haven't really found an answer.

So, I am posting here in the hopes that this is a simple configuration issue.

I've done the following:

- Set up Jenkins as a windows service and installed the Git Plugin
- Used Git-Bash to open a window and create the key pair
- Copied the public key to my Git account
- Cloned the Git repository as directed in the book's example

However, I am seeing the following error message each time Jenkins attempts to pull changes from the Git repository:

Started by an SCM change:

```
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\game-of-life-default
 git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:xxxx-xxxxxx/game-of-life.git
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxxx-xxxxx/game-of-life.git
 git.exe --version
 git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:xxxx-xxxxx/game-of-life.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes

FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:xxxx-xxxxx/game-of-life.git

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@github.com:xxxx-xxxxx/game-of-life.git
```

Comment: Since I'm running Jenkins under Windows 7, I've added a .ssh file to the local system account.  I still get the same error, but now I am also seeing the following: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.

Comment: I just added my credentials in the project configuration with the same results.  Still not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an issue in progress regarding timeout on Jenkins polling Git repo: [JENKINS-20750](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20750)

> We're having a similar problem.. 2008 server, Jenkins 1.560, git-client-plugin 1.8.0.
>
> git polling hangs, strange errors with can't create `~/.ssh` folder... (the folder is there) running as jenkins user on the server, not as system account.
> No `HOMEDRIVE` or `HOMEPATH` environment variables are set.
> We use this script to kill the `>3` minute SCM Polling processes, which seems to get things going again fairly reliably.

```
Jenkins.instance.getTrigger("SCMTrigger").getRunners().each()
{
  item ->
    println(item.getTarget().name)
    println(item.getDuration())
    println(item.getStartTime())
    long millis = Calendar.instance.time.time - item.getStartTime()

    if(millis > (1000 * 60 * 3)) // 1000 millis in a second * 60 seconds in a minute * 3 minutes
    {
      Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().each()
      { 
        tItem ->
          if (tItem.getName().contains("SCM polling") && tItem.getName().contains(item.getTarget().name))
          { 
            println "Interrupting thread " + tItem.getName(); 
            tItem.interrupt()
          }
       }
    }
}
```

> It would be nice if we could set the SCM polling timeout separately from the general GIT one. (1 minute should always be sufficient)